# SharePoint 2010 workflow not triggers when item is created programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint 2010 workflow to send an email on list. when I add item into list using code, it not triggers the workflow. however when I enter Item manually it works fine.

Comment: Are you using RunWithElevatedPrivileges? The workflows don't work when you are using System Account to add item..

Comment: Yes I am using RunWithElevated, However I need it because not all users have the pemission to create list item.

Comment: Through code, are you able add item? did you check whether the item is there or not?

Comment: @Ramesh this might help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56751/workflow-is-not-working-when-use-spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is that workflow not starting automatically as System Account. So don't run the code with system account.

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Workflow not trigger after new item created](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33085/workflow-not-trigger-after-new-item-created)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I went through the following:

- I checked SPTimerV4-- it was running.
- I ran Get-WFFarmStatus and Get-SBFarmStatus-- both were good.
- WF running as System Account: false-- all good.
- Item being created by System Account: false-- all good.
- Checked/unchecked manual start/auto start in Designer, then republished-- done.

None of them worked. (You can google each of the above to perform them accurately.)

At the end of my wits, I thought of recreating the WF. I began with a simple workflow that did nothing but to log a message on the history list. I checked manual/auto at creation. Saved and published. I created an item in the target list.

This new WF ran-- and so did the old problematic WF!

I am thinking that there is an internal create-event hook that broke with the old WF. When the new WF was being hooking into the create event, it restored the hook for the old WF. I will probably never get to confirm this. Just the same, it resolved my issue and that is what matters to me now.

TGBTG!